# How to Query three (3) tables having one Identical field in all and Group the result by another field?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm performing an analysis on a certain warehouse within a java program using SQL as its database.

I have 3 tables; table1 contains the general details of a products, table2 contains the transaction details of the product in one region i.e. Region A and table 3 contains transaction details of the product in the other region, say Region B.
Table1 - General Details

```
id    itemID     itemName         Qty        category
1     TAG01      Acer Laptops     10         Electronics
2     TAG04      Baking Floor     200        Foods
3     TAG08      Philips Bulbs    700        Electronics
4     TAG109     Sweat Pants      85         Wear
```

Table2 - details from Region A

```
id    itemID     sellDate
1     TAG01       "
2     TAG01       "
3     TAG109      "
4     TAG01       "
```

Table3 - details from Region B

```
id    itemID     sellDate
1     TAG109      "
2     TAG109      "
```

I want to select category with its Total Qty from Table1 and attach to it the total number of counts of the distinct itemID from Table2 and Table3

Expect results:

```
id    category         Qty           totalTransactions    
1     Electronics      710           3
2     Foods            200sacks      -  
3     Wear             85            3
```

This is what  I tried and it give satisfying results

```
String sql = "SELECT category, Qty FROM table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT itemID, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT itemID FROM table3 union ALL SELECT itemID FROM table2)t GROUP BY itemID)q"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Java does not allow SQL JOINS"??? Also show us the code you tried...

Comment: 'The Problem is Java does not allow SQL JOINS' - did you get some sort of error when you tried to create a query - if so please add your code and the error

Comment: How you add `200sacks` to something? What type `Qty` column have? `varchar`?

Comment: you can define a view that joins the three tables and let java fetch from the (one) view

Comment: The word "sack"  I used it as a reference so it is not stored in the database hence  the real figure is 200 and also the reason why I say that SQL JOINS are not accepted by JAVA is because i tried them on another kind of query and didn't work then I was  advised to use sub queries which worked in that position...

Comment: Did your try something yourself?

Comment: Within the expected results, where does the ID=1 for Electronics come from? You sum the quantities of each category, but there are 2 different IDs for 'Electronics'.

Comment: in table1 , the Primary key is itemID, table2 primary key is id while its itemID is a foreign key referenced to table1, in table3 primary key = id and itemID is referenced to table1 in expected results any thing can be used as a primary key

Comment: This is what I tried and it didn't work  "SELECT category, Qty FROM `table1` INNER JOIN (SELECT itemID, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT itemID FROM `table3` union ALL SELECT itemID FROM `table4`)t GROUP BY itemID)q
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you need. I am joining against two sub-queries where each query performs a COUNT per itemId and then the SUM of the two is done in the main query plus the SUM of the Qty column.

LEFT JOIN is used since not all rows in table1 might have rows in the transaction tables.

```
SELECT category, SUM(Qty), SUM(IFNULL(t3.c3,0) + IFNULL(t2.c2, 0))
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemId, COUNT(*) c2 FROM table2 GROUP BY itemId) t2 ON t2.itemId = t1.itemID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemId, COUNT(*) c3 FROM table3 GROUP BY itemId) t3 ON t3.itemId = t1.itemID
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: Thank you so much.... It worked... , It seems like I didn't know how to use and when to use alias and Joins...

Comment: The query at first threw an exception `'IFNULL' is not recognized as a function or procedure`  but I simply replaced `IFNULL` with `COALESCE` and it worked because it SQL server that am using